# Mysql data insert issue in timestamp type

Tags: mysql

Using DBeaver we are trying to execute the following query.

```
  UPDATE listing SET ScheduledTime='2019-01-09 15:14:51.0', Status='SCHEDULED' where ID=108
```

after successful execution, we can see the ScheduledTime column as '2019-01-09 20:44:51' in DB. Why there is a time mismatch and how we can solve it? Assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you check if your timezones are matched with the mysql server?

Comment: check the `data type` of `ScheduledTime`. I think you can make this `DateTime` instead of `Timestamp`

Comment: @Kaushik after changing the type also we are getting same result

Answer (score 0):

You use different timezone setting when you store and when you view the data. As mysql documentation on [timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) says:

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis.

Mysql documentation describes how to view and set timezone [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: When executing "SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;" getting @@GLOBAL.time_zone-UTC @@SESSION.time_zone-UTC

Comment: finally, we need to run a scheduler(written in Java) code which compares now() and the time getting from DB.

Comment: Query : "select ID from listing where ScheduledTime < NOW() AND Status='SCHEDULED'"

Comment: The java code may use different timezone setting. The point is: you set the timestamp using X timezone, but retrieve it with Y timezone and the two timezones have 5.5 hours difference (India or Sri Lanka I would say)